# What is meaning of this kind of argument `const types = ({ editor }: { editor: Editor }) => {}`?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I recently looking through 
https://github.com/ory/editor/blob/master/packages/ui/src/Trash/index.js#L89

and found a kind of argument that I don't understand.
Here is the full code:

```
const types = ({ editor }: { editor: Editor }) => {
  const plugins = [
    ...Object.keys(editor.plugins.plugins.layout),
    ...Object.keys(editor.plugins.plugins.content)
  ].map(
    (p: string) =>
      editor.plugins.plugins.content[p].name ||
      editor.plugins.plugins.layout[p].name
  )

  if (editor.plugins.hasNativePlugin()) {
    plugins.push(editor.plugins.getNativePlugin()().name)
  }

  return plugins
}
```

What the argument's meaning? What is it called?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: if you mean `: { editor: Editor }` part it's related to [Flow static typing system](https://flow.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means function will receive an object with editor property in it and has the type of Editor.

For more information you can check https://flow.org/en/

Comment: Looks like a typescript.

Comment: Looks like but it is not. :) it is flow type. You can confirm it by looking to source code. Before imports there is `//@flow `

Answer (score 1):

So there are 2 parts here.

1. You destruct the given arguments and only use the `editor` property
   `{ editor }`
2. You define the [type of the passed object](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/).

Without the type definition it looks something like this. If you know, you only need the editor of a passed object, you can destruct it

```js
// Passing and working with the whole object
const fn1 = ( obj ) => {
  const editor = obj.editor;
  console.log( editor );
};

// Destructing the object and only use the editor property
// Basically the same as fn1 without the whole obj.
const fn2 = ( { editor } ) => {
  console.log( editor );
};

const obj = {
  editor: 'Editor',
};

fn1( obj );
fn2( obj );
```